# How to setup SMTP server on nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I've been trying to setup a simple form that will send an email to the user upon submission. I've been working with nodejs and have installed nodemailer to help aid me. I'm using gmail as the SMTP server, and was encountering some issues. Here is the html:

```
<title> Schedule an Appointment - Name </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/styles.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/script.js"></script>
```

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="page.html"> Home </a><br>
    <br>
    <li><a class="active" href=""> Appointment </a> <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="specsPage.html"> Build </a> <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="contactPage.html"> Contact </a> <br> 
    <br>
</ul>

<div id="schedulePage">
    <h4> Schedule an Appointment </h4>

    <div id="fullForm">

            First Name: <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name..."> <br>
            <br>
            Last Name: <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name..."> <br>
            <br>
            Email: <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..."> <br>
            <br>
            Phone Number: <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Callback Number..."> <br>
            <br>
            <input id="send_email" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <span id="message"></span>


    </div>
</div>
```

And the scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var from,to,subject,text;
$("#send_email").click(function(){      
    to=$("#email").val();
    firstname=$("#firstname").val();
    lastname=$("#lastname").val();
    $("#message").text("Sending E-mail...Please wait");
    $.get("http://localhost:4000/send",{to:to,subject:firstname,text:lastname},function(data){
    if(data=="sent"){
        $("#message").empty().html(" Email is been sent at " + to + " . Please check inbox !");
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: when you say you are `encountering some issues`, do we need to guess what the issues are?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to enable **less secure application** in Gmail 
[How to enable less secure apps in google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

then install node-mailer

`npm i nodemailer`

paste this function in your code

```
     var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://yourmail%40gmail.com:yourpass@smtp.gmail.com');

    // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols

function sendmail(to,subject,text,html,info) {

var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Testing Mail" <youmail@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: to, // list of receivers
    subject: subject, // Subject line
    text: text, // plaintext body
    html: html  // html body
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, infoo){
    var res={
        responsecode:''
    }
    if(error){
        res.responsecode=401;
        return info(new Error(res.responsecode),null);
    }
    res.responsecode=200;
    info(null,res.responsecode+infoo.response);
});}
```

now call the function

```
app.get('/send',function (req,res) {
//pass value from your html form here
sendmail('to', 'subject', 'body', '<h1>its Html</h1>', function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error is " + err)
        return
    }
    console.log("Email sent. " + info)
})})
```