# error when want send mail with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, dns, nodemailer

I have query on node js and nodemailer, I want to send js emails to email account for gmail, but I have errors in a dns module which is not found when running application.

My application is developed on reactions. Upload screeenshot for help

The error that occurs is :

> Error in ./~/nodemailer-direct-transport/lib/direct-transport.js
>   Module not found: 'dns' in C:\Proyectos\ZarateAlarmas\zaw\node_modules\nodemailer-direct-transport\lib
>    @ ./~/nodemailer-direct-transport/lib/direct-transport.js 5:10-24

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knaqr.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41819618/3288890

Comment: check this then update here me here in comment